# Variable is not defined

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a jquery where user selects a category and then a range of years.
my problem is I'm getting `cats is not defined` although it is, and I can see it using `alert(cats);` from `$('[id^="multi-"]').click(function () {`

but when i'm choosing the range of years, from `$("#multi_select_wrapper").keyup(function(){` "cats" variable is not defined

```
$('[id^="multi-"]').click(function () {
            $(this).toggleClass('selected');
            var cats = [];
            $(".selected").each(function(){
                cats.push($(this).attr('data-id'));
            });
            var cats = cats.join(",");
            alert(cats);
    });

            $("#multi_select_wrapper").keyup(function(){
                    if(f_year!==null && t_year!==null){
                            var years = [];
                            var counter = parseInt(t_year)+1;

                            for (var i = f_year; i < counter; i++) {
                                    years.push(i);
                            }
                            alert(years);
                            alert(cats);
                    }
                    $("#multi_search").attr("href", "index.php?do=m&msc=" + cats + "&msy=" + years);
            });
```

Comment: I'm no expert with jquery, but I've done a little bit with javascript. What I see is `cats` is declared in a different scope to `alert(cats);` in the `keyup` event

Comment: please try google first next time

Comment: @ScottSelby: How many relevant results do you think "cats not defined" will give?

Comment: @Blender "javascript variable not defined" gave me a lot...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cats` is only declared inside your click handler function and is not given a value until that click handler runs.  It's value is only available inside that function.

If you want `cats` available outside that function, then you must declare `cats` at a higher scope (e.g. perhaps as a global variable or some higher scope).  Then, it's value could be used anytime AFTER the click handler function runs.

In addition, you shouldn't be declaring the `cats` variable twice in your click handler.  This won't cause an error, but it is incorrect.  Declare it with `var` only once per scope.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the variable scope. You need to move `var cats = [];` outside of the first function

Answer (score 0):

You actually CAN, if you prefer to, define globally accessible variables from within a function by appending them to the window object.

```
window.cats = window.cats ?? []; /* scope 1 */

if (window.cats) { ... /* scope 2 */
```